# How to enable both Basic & Anonymous Authentication in Web.config with default domain?

Tags: c#, iis, asp.net-web-api2, webapi

I have a web API application developed in .Net with framework version 4.6.1, I am trying to enable basic & anonymous authentication using web.config file with default Domain, but its not working expected, anyone help me to enable using web.config.

i have tried the following code, but its not working

```
<system.webServer>
  <security>
    <basicAuthenticaion enabled="true" defaultLogonDomain="DomainName"/>
    <anonymousAuthenticaion enabled="true"/>
  </security>
</system.webServer>
```

Comment: You do understand that IIS's Basic Authentication is not the same thing as HTTP Basic Authentication _in general_? IIS Basic Authentication is only concerned with using Windows Security (and you shouldn't be using it anyway): you don't need to enable Basic Authentication in IIS if you want to use Basic Authentication in ASP.NET if you're using your own authx system.

Comment: yes Dai, Basic authentication is enabled against windows service account,  right now someone needs to enable this in IIS manually, I want to avoid this manual process. For now its working fine when i am doing manually.

Comment: If you enable anonymous authentication, then all other authentication methods are off. You should ask yourself why you want both, as that's impossible by definition.

Answer (score 0):

You should add a tag of `<authentication>` and also pay attention to spelling of `basicAuthentication` and `anonymousAuthentication`(you spell them with `basicAuthenticaion` and `anonymousAuthenticaion`).

```
<system.webServer>
    <security>
      <authentication>
        <basicAuthentication enabled="true"/>
        <anonymousAuthentication enabled="true"/>
      </authentication>
    </security>
</system.webServer>
```

By the way, other authentication methods may be off if you enable anonymous authentication as mentioned by Lex Li in comments. So please check if your requirements need to enable both of them.

Comment: Thanks for you reply, could you please let me know how to add default domain for basicAthenticaion, in other words, if we edit the basic authentication there is an option to edit the default domain, there i need to specify my current dome, how we can add in web.config file

Comment: @Gopinath2105 Just add `defaultLogonDomain` attribute as you mentioned in your question.